# RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py, discord-api

**Код:**

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if message.content == 'ping':
            await message.channel.send('pong')

client = MyClient()
  
client.run('TOKEN')
```

---

**Ошибка:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 256, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 220, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Тимофей/Desktop/BOT/bt.py", line 16, in <module>
    client.run('ТОКЕН ДИСКОРД БОТА')
  File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 260, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x03157418>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 715, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Comment: Токен неправильный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вашу проблему должно решить включение двух пунктов на странице вашего бота. Для этого зайдите в [раздел приложений](https://discord.com/developers/applications) и выберите вашего бота. Затем, слева, на вкладке "Bot"

[image: Бот]

Включите параметры `PRESENCE INTENT` и `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### А еще рекомендую срочно сменить токен

*Делается это на той же вкладке "Bot", нажмите кнопку "Regenerate". Никогда никому не показывайте токен, так как пользователи, получившие доступ к нему, получают доступ также и к вашему боту.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

`discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.`

**Перевожу:**
Был передан неправильный токен

Замените в вашем коде слово `TOKEN` на токен вашего Discord бота.

Comment: Сообщение было опубликовано в качестве ответа, но оно не содержит ответа на вопрос. Сообщение может быть правкой, комментарием, другим вопросом, но, возможно, его стоит просто удалить.

Comment: @Danis, человек публикует в качестве вопроса текст ошибки. Очевидно, что он не понимает, в чём она заключается. Моё сообщение подсказывает, что пользователю нужно указать корректный токен и проблема исчезнет.

Comment: лучше это писать в комментарии а не в ответе

Comment: С чего бы вдруг? Какой вопрос - такой ответ.

Comment: я написал свой комментарий и только потом увидел что вы дополнили свой ответ